# How to prevent images in a flex-box from moving following one another according to their size each time?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am updating 2 images by click, each one probably has a different size and ratio every time. When one of them changes, the other one follows. I have them far enough from each other, so they do not need to do that. I want to them independent, stable.

I tried with and without flex-box. The same thing happens always. The only thing that works is setting position to absolute or fixed, but it destroys the appearance of course.

```
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
#dog1, #dog2{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 400px;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you include a little html for the layout too? We probably don't need the js but it wouldn't hurt. What have you tried for `justify-content` settings in the css for your section?

Comment: When I say "follows" I mean its position changes, the ratio is fine.

Comment: Also, I want to mention that by every click only one of them changes, the other one stays the same image, it just moves.

Comment: None of that makes any sense without a diagram or your html to see what is happening.

Comment: <section>
<img id="dog1" src="https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/lhasa/n02098413_10144.jpg" alt=""></img>
<img id="dog2" src="https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/lhasa/n02098413_10144.jpg" alt=""></img>
</section>

Comment: justify-content works okay, I tried everything, but this problem remains.

Comment: You can see all of it here:https://codepen.io/Aikaterini_/pen/RmpQWV

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody who checked it. I noticed that the problem appeared when the width was changing, so instead of max-width, I set a spesific width to the images. Still, if I wanted the width to be random and unique for every picture, it would not work. But, at least, they are stable now. If anybody has an idea how to do that though, it would be perfect.